# angular 2 material checkbox inside material chips not working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using angular 2 with material. I want to add `md-checkbox` inside `md-chip`. But when I add `md-checkbox` inside `md-chip` component, checkbox is not getting checked and the `ngModelChange` event is not fired.

```
<md-chip-list>
  <md-chip>
    <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="season" name="ss" value="joo" (ngModelChange)="changed()">Check me!</md-checkbox>
  </md-chip>
</md-chip-list>
```

Working plunker:  https://plnkr.co/edit/YNsaNrmWFjyaFl5cOUhg?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by click event conflicts between `md-chip` and `md-checkbox`. Based on your requirement, you can disable the click event of `md-chip` by setting `disabled` to true.

```
<md-chip disabled="true">
    <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="season" name="ss" value="joo" (ngModelChange)="changed()">
        Check me!
    </md-checkbox>
</md-chip>
```

refer **[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/o9GXlseMLWyHCBUu7i3s?p=preview)**.